# Prevent TreeBuilder from returning empty array for undefined param

Tags: symfony

I am using the [`TreeBuilder`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html) to load Configuration for my Bundle. That data is used in an angularJs Extension.

Now even if i make an array optional and do not define it in the config.yaml that gets parsed by the `TreeBuilder`, the returned result has the key of said array in it's collection - which causes the angularJs to crash.

Example Treebuilder:

```
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('acme');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->scalarNode('type')->end()
            ->arrayNode('foo')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('a1')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('a2')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
            ->arrayNode('bar')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('b1')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('b2')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

Example config.yaml

```
acme:
    type: "you"
    bar: 
        b1: "get"
        b2: "it"
```

Example Result:

```
{type: "you", foo: {}, bar: {b1: "get", b1: "it"}}
```

The Outcome i need:

```
{type: "you", bar: {b1: "get", b1: "it"}}
```

The `foo` part is not defined in my config.yaml yet i can not get the TreeBuilder to NOT put it in the output.

Obviously the structure is a lot more complex and i consider parsing the resulting array and using `unset` to delete certain empty arrays a dirty solution.

Comment: You did not use any `addDefaultIfNotSet` anywhere in your configuration ?

Comment: I don't want it to have a default value. I want the key to not exist.